# IntelliJ: Can't specify/create App Server for Web Application

Tags: intellij-idea, application-server

I'm attempting to create the simple web application described at [https://techtwaddle.co.in/blog/2015/03/29/creating-a-simple-java-web-app-using-intellij-idea-and-setting-up-remote-debugging/][1]

Intellij 2019.2.3 Ultimate Edition

I select 'Java Enterprise', and check the 'Web Application' checkbox.

Another step is to select the Application Server.

But, the drop-down for Application Server is empty, and clicking the 'New...' button yields just 'New Server' (which is disabled) and 'Nothing here'.

I've installed and verified that I have a Tomcat server running, but after several hours of net searching and experimenting, I can't figure out what I need to do to specify and/or set up the Application Server.

And a query to NetBrains hasn't been answered after 2 days.

Help!

Thanks...

Comment: Do you have Tomcat plug-in enabled in IntelliJ IDEA? See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html. You should be able to [add the servers here](https://i.imgur.com/gSLaFky.png).

Comment: Thanks for the response... I already enabled the 'Smart Tomcat' plugin (3.0.1), but that didn't help.  As an experiment, I enabled the GlassFish plugin, and lo and behold, the GlassFish server appears in the list, but of course still not an entry for Tomcat.  Might there be some other additional plug-in that's required to enable Tomcat to show up?

Comment: Actually, what happens now is that when I click the plus sign, I get a dialog that I can use to configure Glassfish - which I haven't bothered to do yet because I haven't downloaded the GF server, since it's my Tomcat server that I'd like to use.

Comment: Finally got it: also requires enabling the 'Tomcat and TomEE Integration' plugin - and suffixing the path with '/'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I uninstalled and reinstalled IntelliJ Ultimate and it worked.